# How to enable automatic change of guest resolution to fit Boxes window?

Tags: virtual-machine, gnome-boxes

I am using Windows 10 as a guest in a virtual machine on Debian "bullseye" in GNOME Boxes 3.38.0-1 on a laptop with Ryzen 5 4500U processor, which comes with AMD® Renoir integrated graphics. I have [SPICE tools](https://www.spice-space.org/download.html) installed on the guest.

I know that the Spice agent provides "[dynamic resolution changes when the client window is resized/full-screened](https://www.spice-space.org/spice-user-manual.html)". Linux guest machines do resize automatically on this computer if `spice-vdagent` is installed, but this Windows 10 guest machine does not do so for some reason. How do I enable it to change resolution to fit the Boxes window when resized?

Here is the part of the XML configuration of the guest machine for video:

```xml
    <video>
      <model type="virtio" heads="1" primary="yes">
        <acceleration accel3d="no"/>
      </model>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0"/>
    </video>
```

I tried changing acceleration to "yes", but, expectedly, it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `virt-manager` and looked for other video options to try. By trial, changing video device from `virtio` to `qxl` enabled automatic change of the resolution to fit the current window.

Now, the XML configuration part of the guest machine for video looks like this:

```xml
    <video>
      <model type="qxl" ram="65536" vram="65536" vgamem="16384" heads="1" primary="yes">
        <acceleration accel3d="no"/>
      </model>
      <alias name="video0"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0"/>
    </video>
```